# How can I conditionally replace tokens in a config file with Capistrano or Phing?

Tags: php, deployment, capistrano, phing

I would like to try out Capistrano to deploy a PHP application but can't see an option for replacing tokens in config files for different environments.

I'm using the Slim microframework which just uses an array in index.php for config variables like database username etc. I would like to put tokens such as %dbuser% in there which would be replaced at deploy time based on whether I am deploying to staging or production.

Is this possible in Capistrano? Or would I use something like Phing to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Phing, if your deployment is Phing based, you could use the [ReplaceTokens filter](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixD2-CoreFilters.html#ReplaceTokens).

Example <strike>(not tested)</strike>:

```
<target name="-modify-config"
        hidden="true" description="Modifies the xyz.conf ">
  <copy file="${some.directory}/xyz.conf.dist"
        tofile="${some.directory}/xyz.conf"
        overwrite="true" >
    <filterchain>
      <replacetokens begintoken="%" endtoken="%">
        <token key="KEY_A" value="${value.a}" />
        <token key="KEY_B" value="${value.b}" /> 
      </replacetokens>
    </filterchain>
  </copy>
</target>
```